# facebook payment subscription, price hardcoded

Tags: java, facebook, payment, subscription

As I could see [facebook payment subscription documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/) the price is hardcoded in the open-graph html object (fbpayment:price) which is referenced each time a subscription is created. I would like to know if there is some work around to set the price at the time a user creates the subscription. I.e. some kind of parameter into the subscription order or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be misreading that document, but from that documentation:

```
There may be zero or more `alternate_price` properties, to allow the application to price subscriptions differently for different currencies.
```

and

```
An app can define multiple subscriptions associated with the app. However a user can have only one active subscription at any time for that app.
```

Doesn't that cover your use-case?

Comment: Thanks Igy for answering. I'm afraid it's not what I'm looking for. I mean, I would like to set the subscription price dinamically, i.e.: if the user is buying N items in his session, I would like charge that user, on a monthly basis, for those N items (that price is set on runtime), if the same user choose another K items, the application will charge him (on a monthly, or weekly basis) for those items, and presumably with a different price set at runtime as well. I suspect that cannot be done (at the moment), but I would like to be sure.

Comment: I think the workaround for your case is to define subscriptions at various price points, charge the user whichever price point matches their chosen items, and apply the specific items on your side - i.e the user subscribes to 'a bundle @ 20.00', but the specifics of what's included for that bundle are handled elsewhere

Comment: I think that would be the way, If it depends on me, that would be the workaround, but unfortunately life is not easy :(

Comment: Well you could probably create a subscription object for each combination of bonuses that someone purchases, but it would probably be easier to have defined price points and let the user choose what bonuses fit into that price point (i.e 'you chose package A, you can choose 6 of these, and 4 of these') - if the API doesn't support what you want to do with the API you'll need to do something else